# How can I prove the sequence $a_n$ converges if

Tags: convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

$\{a_{kn}\}_{n=1,2,...}$ converges for all integer $k>1$. 
I tried to use the definition of convergence, but it needs another lemma: 
*Can we cover all natural numbers by multiple of prime numbers?* 
Please give me any hints or answers for this problem.

Comment: Yes: see the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic

Comment: Consider $a_n=1$ if $n$ is a prime number, and $a_n=0$, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Define $$a_n=\begin{cases}
ne^{-n+p}&,\quad n=p^k , \text{for prime }p\text{ and positive integer }k
\\
0&,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
then all the subsequences of kind $\{a_{kn}\}$ converge to $0$, while $a_n$ itself does not.